# How to create a 1px border-collapsed table grid that resizes properly even if zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datagrid

Okay. After much effort and annoyance, I have created a rather competent design of a 1px-bordered 15*15 grid that displays properly at different zoom levels. However, trying to compensate for min-width and min-height is a pain. This is necessary because the grid will become disproportionate at 150+% zoom as as there does not yet exist a css property like `min-width: intrinsic' for inline-block values. And while I can simply specify a default min-width that I feel will not be crossed, that seems like a bit of hack. I want to do this properly.

As grids are one of the rare instances where I can and actually probably should use tables, I would like to use a table. (Yay.) If I can get my table to work correctly, I'll simply set min-width as my preferred table width (and height), job done.

However, I find tables to be annoyingly quirky and quite unpredictable at different zoom levels. Firefox does not always display table-cell widths equally, and even causes weird irregular variations in the border-width of some cells. Chrome doesn't seem to keep the table square if I don't define widths on `td`s themselves (which kind of defeats the purpose of using a table in the first place). Display: table has the same sad behavior. And I don't even want to know what the heck IE does. Am I missing something?

I would appreciate some help to create a true table that looks like my following code, yet maintains its shape and grid-border PROPERLY at different `devicePixelRatios` (and on different browsers).

```
<style>
.squares { border-left: 1px #bcafaf solid; border-top: 1px #bcafaf solid; float: left;
  background: black; }
</style>

<div id = "board" style = "display: inline-block; border: 1px brown solid;"></div>
<script src = 'jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
for (var i=0;i<225;i++) { 
$('#board').append( $('<div/>',{ 'class':"squares", width:'2.0rem', height : '2.0rem', id : 'x'+(i+1) }) ); 
    if (i%15===0) { $('.squares').eq(i).css({ clear: 'left' }); } 
}
});
// code for adding border-right and border-bottom for necessary squares, etc
</script>
```

Thanks greatly

**Note:** At this point I'm using absolute rem values to avoid browser squishing issues on zoom (and also if the browser window is too small) - although now I'll probably have to use that everywhere.

Comment: it's very hard for me to understand what you're trying to accomplish. when you say "zoomed", are you referring to actually zooming in and out of a webpage or are you referring to a "percentage" type of table that resizes properly depending on device width?

Comment: Zooming in and out of a webpage

Answer (score 0):

I've had the "pleasure" of having to work with table styling for the last 2 years... (sweet! I know). I've learned a few ways of taming them and once you know these simple little tricks you will be stylin' tables like it's 1999.

### HTML

**Start off with your html looking something like this:**

```
<table class="flipscroll">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="width10">10% Width</th>            
        <th class="width20">20% Width</th>
        <th class="width10">10% Width</th>
        <th class="width10">10% Width</th>
        <th class="width50">50% Width</th>
    </tr>
</thead>            

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

### CSS

**First set your default styles to "border-box (this alone takes care of so many problems and I recommend you use it on every website you build in the future!)"**

```
/* Default Styles */
*, *:after, *:before { margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;  }
```

**Then apply table styles:**

```
/* Table styles */
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-spacing: 0 !important; } 
table * { border: 1px solid black; }
```

**Instead of setting widths on tds, go a step above (literally) and set your widths on the th's in your thead:**

```
    /* Table widths (controled only by <th>) */
    .width10 { width: 10%; }
    .width20 { width: 20%; }
    .width50 { width: 50%; }
```

Now, that will get your table at a good state.. If you want to go above and beyond that you will have to add some media queries and transform your table into "block" and "inline-block" elements.

Here's an example of everything completed: http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/MJ2nt/5/

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but your table still doesn't resize properly on zoom in firefox. The borders have strange anomalous widths at smaller device pixel ratios (zoom levels). And it would be kind of difficult to properly use set widths and heights of 15% of 100...6.6666667.

Comment: I think I know what you're saying now... as some borders look like 2px widte, others keep the 1px width, and when zoomed in even further some are completely missing. Possibly look into "dppx", their might be some answers there/ future answers (probably not a lot of compatibility). Chrome makes everything look fine. FireFox browser bugs...